# Oracle LIKE condition returning empty results

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I want to run a "Like query" in sqlplus, but the query is not returning the expected results. Here is the query.

```
select *
from field
where id like 'D.2._';
```

I am expecting the results which include id D.2.1, D.2.2, D.2.3 etc (but not D.2.11).

What am I missing? I need this query working in Sqlplus and the SQL developer.

Comment: I am getting the empty result.

Answer (score 6):

Probably you have spaces in column:

```
select *
from field
where TRIM(id) like 'D.2._';
```

---

I suggest altering schema and use `VARCHAR2(10)` datatype instead of `CHAR(10)`.

```
select *
from field
where id like 'D.2._';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4a2a0276f34f02ee4bc40ff41b808520)**

Comment: thanks, it worked, but the records don't have spaces in the column 'id'. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @KamalAshrafGill Please post column datatype

Comment: The data type of column 'id' is char(10).

Comment: CHAR(10) is space padded.

Comment: @lad2025 . . . In Oracle, `varchar2()` is usually recommended.

Comment: @KamalAshrafGill: CHAR columns are right-padded with blanks so they are always (in this case) 10 characters long - so if you insert `D.2.1` into the column the database adds five blanks. That's why VARCHAR2 is almost always used.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, VARCHAR2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select *
from field
where id like 'D.2.%' and id <> 'D.2.11';
```